# Retrieve a single entity's nvarchar field in ms crm4 using c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-4, nvarchar

This is my code so far, im trying to retirieve the nvarchar string value of kez_customparamvalue. Normally for a decimal or float id use something like CrmDecimalProperty hoursAsCrmNumber = hours as CrmDecimalProperty; but im unsure as to what to do in the case of a nvarchar.

```
public string Retrieve_SC_Target_Rate()
    {

        try
        {

            // Create the retrieve target.
            TargetRetrieveDynamic targetRetrieve = new TargetRetrieveDynamic();

            // Set the properties of the target.
            targetRetrieve.EntityName = EntityName.kez_custimizationpararmeter.ToString();
            targetRetrieve.EntityId = new Guid ("D739150F-F68B-E211-AD2B-00155D011F06");

            // Create the request object.
            RetrieveRequest retrieve = new RetrieveRequest();

            // Set the properties of the request object.
            retrieve.Target = targetRetrieve;

            // Create the column set object that indicates the properties to be retrieved.
            ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();
            cols.Attributes = new string[] { "kez_customparamvalue" };
            // Set the properties of the column set.
            retrieve.ColumnSet = cols;

            // Indicate that the BusinessEntity should be retrieved as a DynamicEntity.
            retrieve.ReturnDynamicEntities = true;

            // Execute the request.
            RetrieveResponse retrieved = (RetrieveResponse)svc.Execute(retrieve);

            // Extract the DynamicEntity from the request.
            DynamicEntity entity = (DynamicEntity)retrieved.BusinessEntity;

            Property paramValue = entity.Properties.Where(p => p.Name == "kez_customparamvalue").FirstOrDefault();

            if (paramValue != null)
            {                    
                // reutrn the nvarchar value of paramValue


            }
            return "The value is ";  // + param value 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // The variable 'e' can access the exception's information.
             return e.StackTrace.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use StringProperty which returned the proper value, hope this helps.

```
if (paramValue != null)
            {
                // reutrn the nvarchar value of paramValue
                StringProperty stringParamValue = paramValue as StringProperty;
                return stringParamValue.Value;
            }
```